# Mongoose - validate email syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose schema for users (UserSchema) and I'd like to validate whether the email has the right syntax. The validation that I currently use is the following:

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function (email) {
  return email.length
}, 'The e-mail field cannot be empty.')
```

However, this only checks if the field is empty or not, and not for the syntax.

Does something already exist that I could re-use or would I have to come up with my own method and call that inside the validate function?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a regex. Take a look at this question: [Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

I've used this in the past.

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function (email) {
   var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
   return emailRegex.test(email.text); // Assuming email has a text attribute
}, 'The e-mail field cannot be empty.')
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about the test() method either.

Comment: You should define the regex outside of the function for better performance.

Comment: This regex fails to validate some valid emails, such as those include the plus sign on the lefthand side.

Comment: What exactly is this `email.text` attribute?

Comment: @chovy the email.text attribute is basically the email address string. For example "myemail@gmail.com"

Comment: can't help but notice the end part, is that any word between 2-4 chars long? does this mean an email like info@company.london will not work? the regex is probably wrong.

Comment: @Val these TLDs didn't exist back in 2013. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46181/7770081) for an up-to-date regex

Answer (score 138):

you could also use the **match** or the **validate** property for validation in the schema

example

```
var validateEmail = function(email) {
    var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    return re.test(email)
};

var EmailSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: 'Email address is required',
        validate: [validateEmail, 'Please fill a valid email address'],
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, 'Please fill a valid email address']
    }
});
```

Comment: nice solution. but only problem is it's not passing eslint regex rule. could you please update?

Comment: What's difference between `validate` and `match`?

Comment: @Anatoly `validate` specifies a function to be called for validation (doesn't need to use regexes), `match` specifies a validation regex directly.

Comment: proposed regex allows only 2-3 letter TLD, but there are available longer TLD  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains  

also, single letter TLD is technically correct (even if there're no such at the moment)  

so my suggestion is to use regex with `w+` instead of `w{2,3}`

Comment: plus `+` is a valid character for email and this regex doesn't allow emails like`user+alias@gmail.com`, consider using another regex e.g. `/^.+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+\w+$/`

Answer (score 94):

I use [validator](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) for my input sanitation, and it can be used in a pretty cool way.

Install it, and then use it like so:

```
import { isEmail } from 'validator';
// ... 

const EmailSchema = new Schema({
    email: { 
        //... other setup
        validate: [ isEmail, 'invalid email' ]
    }
});
```

works a treat, and reads nicely.

Comment: for ES5 :) , const validator = require('validator');                                                                                                                  validate: [validator.isEmail, 'invalid email'],

Comment: `const` wasn't available in ES5 unfortunately.

Comment: smaller chuck with `import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';`

Answer (score 14):

The [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)
dosn't play well with mongoose to get rid of the warning set isAsync to false

```
const validator = require('validator');

email:{
type:String,
validate:{
      validator: validator.isEmail,
      message: '{VALUE} is not a valid email',
      isAsync: false
    }
}
```

Comment: without `isAsync: false` , validation was not working in my case, i was using mongoose with promise. mongoose version `5.2.13`

Answer (score 13):

I know this is old, but I don't see this solution so thought I would share:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(v) {
                return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v);
            },
            message: "Please enter a valid email"
        },
        required: [true, "Email required"]
    }
});
```

You can do this for any type you want to validate and just pass the appropriate regex expression. If you google the type you want to validate and it's related regex expression it's easy to find a solution. This will keep your validations consistent and puts all the code in the schema instead of hanging functions.

Comment: very classic solution. can you explain how ``unique`` key work

Comment: @HidaytRahman mongoose will not create the document if another one with that email exists

Answer (score 5):

For some reason <strike>`validate: [ isEmail, 'Invalid email.']`</strike> doesn't play well with `validate()` tests.

```
const user = new User({ email: 'invalid' });
try {
  const isValid = await user.validate();
} catch(error) {
  expect(error.errors.email).to.exist; // ... it never gets to that point.
}
```

But **mongoose 4.x** (it might work for older versions too) has other alternative options which work hand in hand with Unit tests.

**Single validator:**

```
email: {
  type: String,
  validate: {
    validator: function(value) {
      return value === 'correct@example.com';
    },
    message: 'Invalid email.',
  },
},
```

**Multiple validators:**

```
email: {
  type: String,
  validate: [
    { validator: function(value) { return value === 'handsome@example.com'; }, msg: 'Email is not handsome.' },
    { validator: function(value) { return value === 'awesome@example.com'; }, msg: 'Email is not awesome.' },
  ],
},
```

**How to validate email:**

My recommendation: Leave that to experts who have invested hundreds of hours into building proper validation tools. (already answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28396238/2013580) as well)

[`npm install --save-dev validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

```
import { isEmail } from 'validator';
...
validate: { validator: isEmail , message: 'Invalid email.' }
```

Answer (score 4):

Email type for schemas - [mongoose-type-email](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-type-email)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('mongoose-type-email');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: mongoose.SchemaTypes.Email
});
```

**Possible Reference:**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-type-email

Answer (score 2):

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const validateEmail = function(email) {
  const regex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Please enter your email"],
    validate: [validateEmail, "Please enter a valid email"],
    unique: true,
  },


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email: {
    type: String,
    match: [/^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/, `Please fill valid email address`],
    validate: {
      validator: function() {
        return new Promise((res, rej) =>{
          User.findOne({email: this.email, _id: {$ne: this._id}})
              .then(data => {
                  if(data) {
                      res(false)
                  } else {
                      res(true)
                  }
              })
              .catch(err => {
                  res(false)
              })
        })
      }, message: 'Email Already Taken'
    }
  }
```

Comment: do NOT recommend such an approach. As you are defining `User` schema and you are using `User.findOne` before schema was declared.

Answer (score 0):

- Use npm package called `validator` that can give you a bunch of validations out of the box and not only for just the email
- Use `validate` property in your schema on the email field that takes in two nested properties - `validator (Function)` and a `message`. The validator function is where we use the npm package we installed in our first step

**Code**

`npm install validator`

Define schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validatorPackage = require('validator')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      .......
    
      email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'Email address is required'],
        validate: {
          validator: validatorPackage.isEmail,
          message: 'Please provide a valid email',
        },
      },
      .......
      
})

const model = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = model
```