# How to validate email in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im new to Mongoose...I have a code snippet below. If I want to check what comes after the @ symbol in an email before I save, how would I do that validation?

```
var user = new User ({
     firstName: String,
     lastName: String,
     email: String,
     regDate: [Date]
});

user.save(function (err) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a regex. Take a look at this question: Validate email address in JS?

You can try this

```
user.path('email').validate(function (email) {
   var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
   return emailRegex.test(email.text); // Assuming email has a text attribute
}, 'The e-mail field cannot be empty.')
```

Source: [Mongoose - validate email syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022365/mongoose-validate-email-syntax)

Comment: Im not sure I understand this. Do I need an if statement? so if the email ends in "@google.com", for example, it will save as admin and if the email is just valid "something@something.com" it will save as a user

Comment: in that case, inside the validate 
1. After verifying the email is valid
2. Branch an if-else, one for checking the admin mail endings other for inserting the average joe. :)

Comment: If above code doesn't works try to remove .text for email parameter, so it become like this:
____
user.path('email').validate(function (email) {
   var emailRegex = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
   return emailRegex.test(email.text); // Assuming email has a text attribute
}, 'The e-mail field cannot be empty.')
____

Answer (score 2):

You can add validation to the schema: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html