# Building enterprise app with Node/Express

Tags: node.js, express, architecture

I'm trying to understand how to structure enterprise applciation with Node/Express/Mongo (actually using MEAN stack).

After reading 2 books and some googling (including similar StackOverflow questions), I couldn't find any good example of structuring large applications using Express. All sources I've read suggest to split application by following entities:

- routes
- controllers
- models

But the main problem I see with this structure is that controllers are like god objects, they knows about `req`, `res` objects, responsible for validation and *have business logic* included in.

At other side, routes seems to me like over-engineering because all they doing is  mapping endpoints(paths) to controller methods.

I have Scala/Java background, so I have habit to separate all logic in 3 tiers - controller/service/dao.

For me following statements are ideal:

- Controllers are responsible only for interacting with WEB part, i.e. marshalling/unmarshalling, some simple validation (required, min, max, email regex etc);
- Service layer (which actually I missed in NodeJS/Express apps) is responsible only for business logic, some business validation. Service layer doesn't know anything about WEB part (i.e. they can be called from other place of application, not only from web context);
- Regarding to DAO layer is all clear for me. Mongoose models are actually DAO, so it most clear thing to me here.

I think examples I've seen are very simple, and they shows only concepts of Node/Express, but I want to look at some real world example, with much of the business logic/validation involved in.

EDIT:

Another thing isn't clear to me is absent of DTO objects. Consider this example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Article = mongoose.model('Article');
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    // Create a new article object
    const article = new Article(req.body);
    // saving article and other code
}
```

There JSON object from `req.body` is passed as parameter for creating Mongo document. It smells bad for me. I would like to work with concrete classes, not with raw JSON

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178334/folder-structure-for-a-node-js-project  
And this gist:  
https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/1398757

Comment: You can structure it however you see fit. Instead of creating an article directly under the controller, you can always separate it to another layer under a different directory, say Service.createArticle and require it (just like import in java) for usage

Comment: About the req.body object, it should have been converted to Javascript Object if you used express-middleware like body-parser. And yes even if it's not raw JSON anymore, we still don't pass it directly to DTO constructor. it need to pass some validation and sanitization

Comment: There is no right or wrong in structuring a project, different enterprise projects have different structures because they do different things. Some need to support real-time framework like socket.io, some need to have background daemon to consume message queues, and bunches of other stuff. Just structure your app the way you know it, gradually the structure will change as your app scale

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Controllers are God objects until you don't want them to be so...  
*   – you don't say zurfyx (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻*

**Just interested in the solution?** **Jump onto** the latest section **"Result"**.

┬──┬◡ﾉ(° -°ﾉ)

Prior getting started with the answer, let me apologize for making this response way longer than the usual SO length. Controllers alone do nothing, it's all about the whole MVC pattern. So, I felt like it was relevant to go through all important details about Router <-> Controller <-> Service <-> Model, in order to show you how to achieve proper isolated controllers with minimum responsibilities.

## Hypothetical case

Let's start with a small hypothetical case:

- I want to have an API that serves a user search through AJAX.
- I want to have an API that also serves the same user search through Socket.io.

Let's start with Express. That's easy peasy, isn't it?

routes.js

```
import * as userControllers from 'controllers/users';
router.get('/users/:username', userControllers.getUser);
```

controllers/user.js

```
import User from '../models/User';
function getUser(req, res, next) {
  const username = req.params.username;
  if (username === '') {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Username can\'t be blank' });
  }
  try {
    const user = await User.find({ username }).exec();
    return res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
}
```

Now let's do the Socket.io part:

*Since that's not a [socket.io](http://socket.io) question, I'll skip the boilerplate.*

```
import User from '../models/User';
socket.on('RequestUser', (data, ack) => {
  const username = data.username;
  if (username === '') {
    ack ({ error: 'Username can\'t be blank' });
  }
  try {
    const user = User.find({ username }).exec();
    return ack(user);
  } catch (error) {
    return ack(error);
  }
});
```

Uhm, something smells here...

- `if (username === '')`. We had to write the controller validator twice. What if there were `n` controller validators? Would we have to keep two (or more) copies of each up to date?
- `User.find({ username })` is repeated twice. That could possibly be a service.

We have just written two controllers that are attached to the exact definitions of Express and Socket.io respectively. They will most likely never break during their lifetime because both Express and Socket.io tend to have backwards compatibility. **BUT**, they are not reusable. Changing Express for [Hapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi)? You will have to redo all your controllers.

Another bad smell that might not be so obvious...

The controller response is handcrafted. `.json({ error: whatever })`

APIs in RL are constantly changing. In the future you might want your response to be `{ err: whatever }` or maybe something more complex (and useful) like: `{ error: whatever, status: 500 }`

## Let's get started (a possible solution)

I can't call it *the* solution because there is an endless amount of solutions out there. It is up to your creativity, and your needs. The following is a decent solution; I'm using it in a relatively large project and it seems to be working well, and it fixes everything I pointed out before.

I'll go Model -> Service -> Controller -> Router, to keep it interesting until the end.

### Model

I won't go into details about the Model, because that's not the subject of the question.

You should be having a similar Mongoose Model structure as the following:

models/User/validate.js

```
export function validateUsername(username) {
  return true;
}
```

You can read more about the appropriate structure for mongoose 4.x validators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42116795).

models/User/index.js

```
import { validateUsername } from './validate';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { 
    type: String, 
    unique: true,
    validate: [{ validator: validateUsername, msg: 'Invalid username' }],
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

Just a basic User Schema with an username field and `created` `updated` mongoose-controlled fields.

The reason why I included the `validate` field here is for you to notice that you should be doing most model validation in here, not in the controller.

Mongoose Schema is the last step before reaching the database, unless someone queries MongoDB directly you will always rest assured that everyone goes through your model validations, which gives you more security than placing them on your controller. Not to say that unit testing validators as they are in the previous example is trivial.

Read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465414/best-place-to-handle-data-validation-with-mongoose-and-express) and [here](https://thecodebarbarian.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/61/).

### Service

The service will act as the processor. Given acceptable parameters, it'll process them and return a value.

Most of the times (including this one), it'll make use of [Mongoose Models](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) and return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (or a callback; but [I would definitely](http://callbackhell.com/) use ES6 with Promises if you are not doing so already).

services/user.js

```
function getUser(username) {
  return User.find({ username}).exec(); // Just as a mongoose reminder, .exec() on find 
                               // returns a Promise instead of the standard callback.
}
```

At this point you might be wondering, no `catch` block? Nope, because we're going to do a *cool trick* later and we don't need a custom one for this case.

Other times, a trivial sync service will suffice. Make sure your sync service never includes I/O, otherwise you will be blocking [the whole Node.js thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17959663/why-is-node-js-single-threaded).

services/user.js

```
function isChucknorris(username) {
  return ['Chuck Norris', 'Jon Skeet'].indexOf(username) !== -1;
}
```

### Controller

We want to avoid duplicated controllers, so we'll only have **a** controller for each action.

controllers/user.js

```
export function getUser(username) {
}
```

How does this signature look like now? Pretty, right? Because we're only interested in the username parameter, we don't need to take useless stuff such as `req, res, next`.

Let's add in the missing validators and service:

controllers/user.js

```
import { getUser as getUserService } from '../services/user.js'

function getUser(username) {
  if (username === '') {
    throw new Error('Username can\'t be blank');
  }
  return getUserService(username);
}
```

Still looks neat, but... what about the `throw new Error`, won't that make my application crash? - Shh, wait. We're not done yet.

So at this point, our controller documentation would look sort of:

```
/**
 * Get a user by username.
 * @param username a string value that represents user's username.
 * @returns A Promise, an exception or a value.
 */
```

*What's the "value" stated in the `@returns`? Remember that earlier we said that our services can be both sync or async (using `Promise`)? `getUserService` is async in this case, but `isChucknorris` service wouldn't, so it would simply return a value instead of a Promise.*

Hopefully everyone will read the docs. Because they will need to treat some controllers different than others, and some of them will require a `try-catch` block.

Since we can't trust developers (this includes me) reading the docs before trying first, at this point we have to make a decision:

- Controllers to force a `Promise` return
- Service to always return a Promise

*⬑ This will solve the inconsistent controller return (not the fact that we can omit our try-catch block).*

IMO, I prefer the first option. Because controllers are the ones which will chain the most Promises most of the times.

```
return findUserByUsername
         .then((user) => getChat(user))
         .then((chat) => doSomethingElse(chat))
```

If we are using ES6 Promise we can alternatively make use of a nice property of `Promise` to do so: `Promise` can handle non-promises during their lifespan and still keep returning a `Promise`:

```
return promise
         .then(() => nonPromise)
         .then(() => // I can keep on with a Promise.
```

If the only service we call doesn't use `Promise`, we can make one ourselves.

```
return Promise.resolve() // Initialize Promise for the first time.
  .then(() => isChucknorris('someone'));
```

Going back to our example it would result in:

```
...
return Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => getUserService(username));
```

We don't actually need `Promise.resolve()` in this case as `getUserService` already returns a Promise, but we want to be consistent.

*If you are wondering about the `catch` block: we don't want to use it in our controller unless we want to do it a custom treatment. This way we can make use of the two already built-in communication channels (the exception for errors and return for success messages) to deliver our messages through individual channels.*

Instead of ES6 Promise `.then`, we can make use of the newer ES2017 `async / await` ([now official](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/ecmascript-2017.html)) in our controllers:

```
async function myController() {
    const user = await findUserByUsername();
    const chat = await getChat(user);
    const somethingElse = doSomethingElse(chat);
    return somethingElse;
}
```

*Notice `async` in front of the `function`.*

### Router

Finally the router, yay!

So we haven't responded anything to the user yet, all we have is a controller that we know that it ALWAYS returns a `Promise` (hopefully with data). Oh!, and that can possibly throw an exception if `throw new Error is called` or some service `Promise` breaks.

The router will be the one that will, in an uniform way, control petitions and return data to clients, be it some existing data, `null` or `undefined` `data` or an error.

Router will be the ONLY one that will have multiple definitions. The number of which will depend on our interceptors. In the hypothetical case these were API (with Express) and Socket (with Socket.io).

Let's review what we have to do:

We want our router to convert `(req, res, next)` into `(username)`. A naive version would be something like this:

```
router.get('users/:username', (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const result = await getUser(req.params.username); // Remember: getUser is the controller.
    return res.status(200).json(result);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});
```

Although it would work well, that would result in a huge amount of code duplication if we copy-pasted this snippet in all our routes. So we have to make a better abstraction.

In this case, we can create a sort of fake router client that takes a promise and `n` parameters and does its routing and `return` tasks, just like it would do in each of the routes.

```
/**
 * Handles controller execution and responds to user (API Express version).
 * Web socket has a similar handler implementation.
 * @param promise Controller Promise. I.e. getUser.
 * @param params A function (req, res, next), all of which are optional
 * that maps our desired controller parameters. I.e. (req) => [req.params.username, ...].
 */
const controllerHandler = (promise, params) => async (req, res, next) => {
  const boundParams = params ? params(req, res, next) : [];
  try {
    const result = await promise(...boundParams);
    return res.json(result || { message: 'OK' });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
const c = controllerHandler; // Just a name shortener.
```

If you are interested in knowing more about this *trick*, you can read about the full version of this in my other reply in [React-Redux and Websockets with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876889/react-redux-and-websockets-with-socket-io/41309189#41309189) ("SocketClient.js" section).

How would your route look like with the `controllerHandler`?

```
router.get('users/:username', c(getUser, (req, res, next) => [req.params.username]));
```

A clean one line, just like in the beginning.

## Further optional steps

### Controller Promises

It only applies to those who use ES6 Promises. ES2017 `async / await` version already looks good to me.

For some reason, I dislike having to use `Promise.resolve()` name to build the initialize Promise. It's just not a clear what's going on there.

I'd rather replace them for something more understandable:

```
const chain = Promise.resolve(); // Write this as an external imported variable or a global.

chain
  .then(() => ...)
  .then(() => ...)
```

Now you know that `chain` marks the start of a chain of Promises. So does everyone who reads your code, or if not, they at least assume it's a chain a service functions.

### Express error handler

Express does have a default error handler which you should be using to capture at least the most unexpected errors.

```
router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  // Expected errors always throw Error.
  // Unexpected errors will either throw unexpected stuff or crash the application.
  if (Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(Error.prototype, err)) {
    return res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error: err.message });
  }

  console.error('~~~ Unexpected error exception start ~~~');
  console.error(req);
  console.error(err);
  console.error('~~~ Unexpected error exception end ~~~');


  return res.status(500).json({ error: '⁽ƈ ͡ (ुŏ̥̥̥̥םŏ̥̥̥̥) ु' });
});
```

What's more, you should probably be using something like [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) or [winston](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston) instead of `console.error`, which are more professional ways to handle logs.

And that's is how we plug this into the `controllerHandler`:

```
  ...
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500) && next(error);
  }
```

We are simply redirecting any captured error to Express' error handler.

### Error as ApiError

`Error` is considered the default class to encapsulate errors in when throwing an exception in Javascript. If you really only want to track your own controlled errors, I'd probably change the `throw Error` and the Express error handler from `Error` to `ApiError`, and you can even make it fit your needs better by adding it the status field.

```
export class ApiError {
  constructor(message, status = 500) {
    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

## Additional information

### Custom exceptions

You can throw any custom exception at any point by `throw new Error('whatever')` or by using `new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('whatever'))`. You just have to play with [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

### ES6 ES2017

That's very opinionated point. IMO [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) (or even [ES2017](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/ecmascript-2017.html), now having an official set of features) is the appropriate way to work on big projects based on Node.

If you aren't using it already, try looking at [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) features and [ES2017](http://www.2ality.com/2016/02/ecmascript-2017.html) and [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) transpiler.

## Result

That's just the complete code (already shown before), with no comments or annotations. You can check everything regarding this code by scrolling up to the appropriate section.

router.js

```
const controllerHandler = (promise, params) => async (req, res, next) => {
  const boundParams = params ? params(req, res, next) : [];
  try {
    const result = await promise(...boundParams);
    return res.json(result || { message: 'OK' });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500) && next(error);
  }
};
const c = controllerHandler;

router.get('/users/:username', c(getUser, (req, res, next) => [req.params.username]));
```

controllers/user.js

```
import { serviceFunction } from service/user.js
export async function getUser(username) {
  const user = await findUserByUsername();
  const chat = await getChat(user);
  const somethingElse = doSomethingElse(chat);
  return somethingElse;
}
```

services/user.js

```
import User from '../models/User';
export function getUser(username) {
  return User.find({}).exec();
}
```

models/User/index.js

```
import { validateUsername } from './validate';

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: { 
    type: String, 
    unique: true,
    validate: [{ validator: validateUsername, msg: 'Invalid username' }],
  },
}, { timestamps: true });

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

models/User/validate.js

```
export function validateUsername(username) {
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I liked your `controllerHandler` trick. But can you please give me suggestion if  I want to render some view using template engine? I mean `res.render('index', {title: 'Hello'})`. How should look Controller and Route in this case?

Comment: @MyTitle I would avoid modifying controllers. `{title: 'Hello'}` can be the current object values which are already sent to the `handleController`. 'index' should probably be an extra parameter on the `handleController` function, since no controller is interested in the view that's going to render the result.
Depending on your needs, you might want to pass 2 or more views to handle different sorts of results or errors, but to start with I would simply pass it an only view filename, and then have a default error one in the "Express Error Handler" (where it's currently a `res.json`).

Comment: How can I get app instance in controllers. I need to fire some events with `app.emit('some event')`

Comment: Neat `controllerHandler` implementation

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to handle things that are very specific to the route, such as setting a response header. Some routes may need to add a certain header, and some may not. I don't want to pass the whole res object into the controller and set headers in there. I think it should be done from the route, or from additional middleware after the promise has finished executing. I Like this approach, but need a little more flexibility in handling unique scenarios per route.

Answer (score 6):

Everyone has its own way of dividing the project into certain folders.
the structure which I use is

- config
- logs
- routes
- controllers
- models
- services
- utils
- app.js/server.js/index.js (any name u prefer)

config folder contain configuration files like database connection settings for all phase of development like "production","development","testing"

example

```
'use strict'
var dbsettings = {
    "production": {
//your test settings
    },
    "test": {

    },
    "development": {
        "database": "be",
        "username": "yourname",
        "password": "yourpassword",
        "host": "localhost",
        "connectionLimit": 100
    }
}
module.exports = dbsettings
```

log folder contain your connection logs error logs for debugging

controller is for validating your req data and business logic

example

```
const service = require("../../service")
const async = require("async")
exports.techverify = (data, callback) => {

    async.series([
        (cb) => {
            let searchObject = { accessToken: data.accessToken }
            service.admin.get(searchObject, (err, result) => {
                if (err || result.length == 0) {
                    callback(err, { message: "accessToken is invalid" })
                } else {
                    delete data.accessToken
                    service.tech.update(data, { verified: true }, (err, affe, res) => {
                        if (!err)
                            callback(err, { message: "verification done" })
                        else
                            callback(err, { message: "error occured" })
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    ])
}
```

models is for defining your db schema

example mongoDb schema

```
'use strict'
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let schema = mongoose.Schema;
let user = new schema({
    accesstoken: { type: String },
    firstname: { type: String },
    lastname: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    image: { type: String },
    phoneNo: { type: String },
    gender: { type: String },
    deviceType: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    regAddress: { type: String },
    pincode: { type: String },
    fbId: { type: String, default: 0 },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    one_time_password: { type: String },
    forgot_password_token: { type: String },
    is_block: { type: Boolean, default: 0 },
    skin_type: { type: String },
    hair_length: { type: String },
    hair_type: { type: String },
    credits: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    invite_code: { type: String },
    refered_by: { type: String },
    card_details: [{
        card_type: { type: String },
        card_no: { type: String },
        card_cv_no: { type: String },
        created_at: { type: Date }
    }]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', user);
```

services is for writing your data base query *avoid writing queries in controller try to write query in this folder and call it in the controller*

queries using mongoose

```
'use strict'
const modelUser = require('../../models/user');
exports.insert = (data, callback) => {
    console.log('mongo log for insert function', data)
    new modelUser(data).save(callback)
}
exports.get = (data, callback) => {
    console.log('mongo log for get function', data)
    modelUser.find(data, callback)
}
exports.update = (data, updateData, callback) => {
    console.log('mongo log for update function', data)
    modelUser.update(data, updateData, callback);
}
exports.getWithProjection = (data, projection, callback) => {
    console.log('mongo log for get function', data)
    modelUser.find(data, projection, callback)
}
```

utils is for common utility function which is commonly used in your project maybe like encrypt,decrypt password etc

example

```
exports.checkPassword = (text, psypherText) => {
    console.log("checkPassword executed")
    console.log(text, psypherText)
    return bcrypt.compareSync(text, psypherText)
}
exports.generateToken = (userEmail) => {
    return jwt.sign({ unique: userEmail, timeStamp: Date.now }, config.keys.jsonwebtoken)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rohit salaria's answer basically explains the same app structure you are used to in java.

- Controllers are the Controllers in Java
- Models are the Data Access Layer
- Services are the Service Layer

I have a few remarks though. The first and most important one is that this is not Java. It may sound obvious but just look at your question and see that you are for looking the same development experience with the same concepts you got used in the Java world. My following remarks are just the explanation for this.

Missing DTOs. In Java they are just required, period. In a Java web application, where you store your data in a relational database and sending and receiving data to the front-end in JSON, it is natural that you convert the data to a Java object. However in a Node app everything is javascript and JSON. That is one of the strengths of the platform. With JSON being the common data format, it is not needed to write code or depend on libraries to translate between the data format of your layers.

Passing the data object directly from the request to the model. Why not? Having JSON as the common data format from the front-end to the database enables you to easily synchronize the data model of your app between all your layers. Of course you don't have to go this way, but it is sufficient most of the time, so why not use it? As for validation it is done in the model, where it belongs according to the MVC theory (, and not in the controller where laziness and pragmatism often puts it :)).

For the final thought I want to add, that this is not the best platform when it comes to project size scaling. It is nod bat at all, but Java is better in that aspect.

Answer (score 0):

simple and basic rule

1. > Keep components associated close to each other.
2. > Divide the page into components and work
3. > All the dependent components should be together
4. > shared things should be kept independent of all the other components .

> Finally every language is sweet. Its just that how familiar you are with the          language.You can only win the battle if you familiar with you sword.

i am developing Angular2 application using NodeJS,Angular2 i'll help you with my directory structure.

[image: main Module]

```
`the main module`
```

[image: subModule]

```
 `the sub module structure`
```

[image: shared Module]

```
`keep the shared folder as a separate module`
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: For waht we need a shared folder ?

Comment: the component, services , directives which is shared accross all the project and is common.